# Getting Lat, Long of clicked location using Leaflet API?

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet

I am using OSM with Leaflet API. Now I want to get the lat and long of a clicked location. I meant something similar to this. ex: `http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click.html`

```
map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
            var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
                alert("Lat, Lon : "+position.lon.toFixed(3),position.lat.toFixed(3));

        });
```

This code in OpenLayers helps to get the lat ,long values... looking for something similar using Leaflet...

Answer (score 70):

You can easily get click events using the map's 'on' event subscription method:

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    alert("Lat, Lon : " + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Reverse geocoding with esri-leaflet and openstreetmap tile.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0], 2);
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  var geocodeService = L.esri.Geocoding.geocodeService();

  map.on('click', function (e) {
    geocodeService.reverse().latlng(e.latlng).run(function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      alert(result.latlng)
    });
  });
```

Source Code: https://github.com/CTRLTAB-WORKS/reverse-geocoding

Comment: A bit contradictory to provide a proprietary library (esri) with much more complicated solution than the native open source Leaflet functions provided by the other answer.... almost 8 years after.